# Can I conditionally check the value of a macro using the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I know I can use the C preprocessor to conditionally compile something like:

```
#define USESPECIALFEATURE

#if defined USESPECIALFEATURE
usespecialfeature();
#endif
```

But I am wondering if I can do something like this:

```
#define USEDFEATURE 4

#if defined USEDFEATURE == 4
usefeature(4);
#endif
```

In other words, I want to use the preprocessor to check the value of a particular macro definition. This doesn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
#define MACRO 10

#if MACRO == 10
enable_feature(10);
#endif
```

Drop the `define` statement, as it checks **whether a macro is defined**, not whether the macro has a specific value.

You can use a variety of arithmetics, too:

```
#if MACRO > 10
#if MACRO < 10
#if MACRO + ANOTHER > 20
#if MACRO & 0xF8
#if MACRO^ANOTHER
#if MACRO > 10 && MACRO < 20
```

... and chain the conditionals:

```
#if MACRO == 1
enable_feature(1);
#elif MACRO == 2
enable_feature(2);
#endif
```

Comment: You could mention you do not even need to check if an identifier is defined before testing its value. In `#if` and `#elif` statements, undefined identifiers are treated as zero.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is possible, but you are using it wrong.

```
#define YOUR_MACRO    3

#if YOUR_MACRO == 3
    do_job(3);
#endif
```

No `defined` check if you want to compare with value. If your macro is not defined, it evaluates to `0` on `#if` check:

```
#if NOT_DEFINED_MACRO
do_something();
#endif
```

Code above is equal to:

```
#if 0
do_something();
#endif
```